# Filter out certain fields during deserialization in Jackson?

Tags: kotlin, jackson

I have the following class that I deserialize incoming JSON:

```kotlin
data class Foo(
    val result: List<Map<String, Any>>,
)
```

I want to filter out specific keys from it.

For instance, if `Map` contains the key `foo`, I want to remove it.

I know that there are `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotations, but I don't think that they're useful on a `Map`.

Currently, I filter the map, but I wonder if there is a more Jackson-specific way to do this (e.g. using filters).

Comment: See See https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations?tab=readme-ov-file#annotations-for-ignoring-properties

Comment: @nitind I wonder how I can use `@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "extra", "uselessValue" })` on `Map` that is inside a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still add the annotations using mixins - more specifically [ObjectMapper.addMixin(target, mixinSource)](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.14.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#addMixIn-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-).

> Method to use for adding mix-in annotations to use for augmenting specified class or interface. All annotations from mixinSource are taken to override annotations that target (or its supertypes) has.

Let's say this is your mixin:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"k1", "k2", "k3"})
record MapMixin() {
}
```

All annotations on `MapMixin` will be added to `Map`s using the method above:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(Map.class, MapMixin.class);

Map<String, Object> map = Map.of(
    "qwe", 11, 
    "k3", "v",
    "rty", "t", 
    "k2", 3
);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(map));
```

The above example will serialize the map as:

```
{
  "rty": "t",
  "qwe": 11
}
```